# Property of simplicity and semi-simplicity under base change of base field

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, hecke-algebras

Suppose $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ and $A$ is a $K$-algebra. Let $F$ be a field extension of $K$ and let $M$ be an $A$-module. What can we say about simplicity or semi-simplicity of $A_F$-module $M_F$ regarding simplicity or semi-simplicity of $M$? For instance I am asking about Hecke Algebras.

Comment: In this generality, not much (except the obvious that simplicity of $M_F$ implies that of $M$)!  Do you have any more hypotheses that might be relevant?

Answer (score 3):

If $K$ is a perfect field, $A$ is a finite dimensional $K$-algebra and $F/K$ is an extension, then $M_F$ is semisimple over $A_F$ for any simple $A$-module $M$.

First note that if $J(R)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of a ring $R$, then $J(A_F)=F\otimes_K J(A)$ of $A$.  Indeed, trivially $F\otimes_K J(A)$ is a nilpotent ideal.  But $A_F/(F\otimes_K J(A))\cong (A/J(A))_F$. Now since $K$ is a perfect field, every semisimple $K$-algebra (in particular, $A/J(A)$) is a [separable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separable+algebra) $K$-algebra, and hence $(A/J(A))_F$ is semisimple.  We conclude that $J(A_F)=F\otimes_K J(A)$.

Since $J(A)$ annihilates $M$, trivially $F\otimes_K J(A)$ annihilates $M_F$.  Thus $M_F$ is a $A_F/(F\otimes_K J(A))= A_F/J(A_F)$-module and hence semisimple.

This argument works so long as $A/J(A)$ is separable over $K$.

Comment: I notice you don't say $A$ is finite dimensional.  If your simple module is finite dimensional you can replace $A$ by its image under the corresponding representation and the same argument goes through.  If the simple is infinite dimensional then I'm not sure